# How to use .live() of jQuery to animate a page after loading

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );
```

How to let it do animation after the page load? Currently is

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click',function(e) {
```

but I want it do animation after the page load without clicking anything.

I tried to change the 'click' to 'load' but look not working.

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('load',function(e) {
```

Original Code :

```
(function($) {
```

/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});
```

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

```
$.fn.reveal = function(options) {


    var defaults = {  
        animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    }; 

    //Extend dem' options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

    return this.each(function() {
```

/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/

```
        var modal = $(this),
            topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
            topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
            modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');
```

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/

```
        if(modalBG.length == 0) {
            modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
        }
```

/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/

```
        //Entrance Animations
        modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
          modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
            $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
            if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                }
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                } 
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                    unlockModal()               
                }
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:open');
        }); 

        //Closing Animation
        modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
          if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                        modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                }       
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:close');
        });
```

/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/

```
        //Open Modal Immediately
    modal.trigger('reveal:open')

        //Close Modal Listeners
        var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
          modal.trigger('reveal:close')
        });

        if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
            modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
            modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });
        }
        $('body').keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
        });
```

/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/

```
        function unlockModal() { 
            locked = false;
        }
        function lockModal() {
            locked = true;
        }   

    });//each call
}//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

HTML :

```
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" id="first_load"></a>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal reveal-modal-1">
        <a class="close-reveal-modal hvr-push"></a>
        <div id="dotype">
            <div class="type-wrap">
                <div id="typed-strings">
                <p>Hey there, I lost my ingredients<br> yesterday at the city. I was going <br> to make you a birthday cake.<br> Can you help me to find it?</p>
                </div>
            <span id="typed"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That title is unlikely to have anyone arriving on your question well disposed towards it.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: Thank you for edit the title.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as it is deprecated.  To make events happen when the document has loaded you can use the following event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

**Full example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div").animate({top: "200px"}, 4000);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1pt solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  Animate on load example
</div>
```

Comment: I tired it do not work for me. The original is look like this  $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
  $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
 });

Comment: @AndersonKoh - I have provided a full example, see if this helps.

Comment: That look cool but It won't fadein when my page done load. Do i show you my full coding?

Comment: @AndersonKoh - If you can provide your full code in your question that would be useful to me and others.

Comment: @AndersonKoh - in your question.  Only post parts that are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I added this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-reveal-id]').delay(500).trigger('click');
});
```

Under

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});
```

Thank you. I solve the problem my self.

I also do this for delay.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('a[data-reveal-id]').delay(500).trigger('click');
    }, 800);
});
```